# How to create an object from a list of lists?

Tags: python, class

I have a list of elements in the following manner:

```
lst = [['Adam','Class 1','English'],['Will','Class 3','Physics'],['George','Class 1','Maths'],['Sofia','Class 2','Chemistry']]
```

Now, I want to convert each of the inner lists into the following object.

```
class Student:
def __init__(self, name, class, subject):
self.name = name
self.class = class
self.subject = subject
```

I am trying the following command to create objects:

```
student_objs = {(name, class, subject): Student(student[0],student[1],student[2]) for student in lst}
```

However, this is giving an error. Suggestions please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue is `class` is a reserved keyword in Python, and trying to use that in list comprehension would not be a good idea, and may lead to errors. Name it something else. And then you can do:

```
lst = [['Adam','Class 1','English'],['Will','Class 3','Physics'],['George','Class 1','Maths'],['Sofia','Class 2','Chemistry']]
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, Class, subject):
        self.name = name
        self.Class = Class
        self.subject = subject
student_objs = {tuple(student): Student(*student) for student in lst}
print(student_objs)
```

Output:

```
{('Adam', 'Class 1', 'English'): <__main__.Student at 0x9bee668>,
 ('Will', 'Class 3', 'Physics'): <__main__.Student at 0x9bee390>,
 ('George', 'Class 1', 'Maths'): <__main__.Student at 0x9beef28>,
 ('Sofia', 'Class 2', 'Chemistry'): <__main__.Student at 0x9beeda0>}
```

Also, your original code would have worked if you had named `class` as something else, and did this,

```
student_objs = {(name, Class, subject): Student(name, Class, subject) for name, Class, subject in lst}
```

Answer (score 2):

The biggest problem with your approach is that you are trying to use undeclared variables `(name, class, subject)`. These are defined only in class Student. What you want to do is `(subject[0], subject[1], subject[2])` instead, or simply use Pythons built-in function `tuple(subject)`.

Another important thing is that you cannot use `class` as variable name! This is reserved keyword in Python. Instead, use `className` for example. So like this:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, className, subject):
        self.name = name
        self.className = className
        self.subject = subject
```

You cannot create and object from "list comprehension". What you can do is

```
student_objs = [Student(student[0], student[1], student[2]) for student in lst]
```

and have array of students.

Answer (score 2):

you cant use the class as an variable name in your Student class as it is a keyword.

The below code does the job for you. But it creates a set rather than obj.

```
lst = [['Adam','Class 1','English'],['Will','Class 3','Physics'],['George','Class 1','Maths'],['Sofia','Class 2','Chemistry']]

class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, _class, subject):
        self.name = name
        self._class = _class
        self.subject = subject

student_objs = {Student(*student) for student in lst}
for obj in student_objs:
    print("name:",obj.name,"\nclass:",obj._class,"\nsubject:",obj.subject)
    print("*"*20)
```

Output:

```
name: Sofia 
class: Class 2 
subject: Chemistry
********************
name: Will 
class: Class 3 
subject: Physics
********************
name: George 
class: Class 1 
subject: Maths
********************
name: Adam 
class: Class 1 
subject: English
********************
```